# How to extract values from outputs of forecasting using a loop as a data frame

Tags: r, lapply, forecasting

I have a df:

```
    head(vardata_num,30)
     wt   ht dist
1  9.00 7.49 5.41
2  8.75 8.03 5.60
3  8.50 7.24 5.30
4  8.50 7.19 5.23
5  8.50 6.94 5.41
6  8.50 7.30 4.52
7  8.50 7.40 2.91
8  8.50 6.97 2.59
9  8.50 7.08 2.08
10 8.50 6.63 1.51
11 8.50 6.73 1.39
12 8.00 6.97 1.76
13 8.00 6.58 1.50
14 8.00 6.90 1.56
15 8.00 6.04 2.43
16 8.00 5.75 2.79
17 8.00 5.72 3.34
18 8.00 5.75 3.53
19 8.00 5.73 3.08
20 7.50 5.45 3.39
21 7.50 5.58 3.34
22 7.50 5.66 4.22
23 7.50 5.71 5.35
24 7.00 5.86 5.99
25 7.00 4.87 6.65
26 7.00 4.87 6.51
27 7.00 4.91 5.34
28 7.00 4.90 4.71
29 7.00 4.83 3.95
30 7.00 4.50 4.9
```

I am trying using a custom function to forecast along these three variables using a loop as under:

```
library(mafs)
ts_lapply <- lapply(vardata_num, function(x) select_forecast(ts(x),test_size = 10, horizon = 3, error = "MAPE"))  # select_forecast() from `mafs` package
```

I am getting the awesome output as below:

> ts_lapply[1] # for one variable

```
$wt
$wt$df_models
        model         ME      RMSE       MAE        MPE      MAPE     MASE      ACF1 best_model runtime_model
1  auto.arima -0.2826189 0.3439279 0.3102743  -4.236451  4.617906 3.149053 0.3624226      tbats          0.25
2        bats -0.1240606 0.1857631 0.1676487  -1.878305  2.479522 1.701510 0.1344866      tbats          1.60
3     croston -0.8903343 0.9183247 0.8903343 -13.164300 13.164300 9.036229 0.4086420      tbats          1.08
4         ets  0.4009141 0.5010641 0.4133541   5.941724  6.126020 4.195235 0.7171674      tbats          0.05
5       meanf -0.3138889 0.3862010 0.3583333  -4.709314  5.322341 3.636816 0.4086420      tbats          0.00
6       naive -0.4250000 0.4808846 0.4250000  -6.339031  6.339031 4.313433 0.4086420      tbats          0.02
7      nnetar -0.9093190 1.0220091 0.9093190 -13.543554 13.543554 9.228909 0.6192314      tbats          1.61
8         rwf -0.4250000 0.4808846 0.4250000  -6.339031  6.339031 4.313433 0.4086420      tbats          0.00
9   rwf_drift -0.3683824 0.4203015 0.3745588  -5.497541  5.582734 3.801493 0.3661817      tbats          0.00
10     snaive -0.4250000 0.4808846 0.4250000  -6.339031  6.339031 4.313433 0.4086420      tbats          0.00
11    splinef  0.3383595 0.4374294 0.3586967   5.014299  5.315592 3.640504 0.7075714      tbats          0.34
12   StructTS  0.2306096 0.3144022 0.2637272   3.405088  3.895718 2.676634 0.6510857      tbats          0.00
13      tbats -0.1240606 0.1857631 0.1676487  -1.878305  2.479522 1.701510 0.1344866      tbats          3.58
14     thetaf -0.4280973 0.4842184 0.4280973  -6.385061  6.385061 4.344868 0.4107693      tbats          0.02

$wt$best_forecast
    Point Forecast    Lo 80    Hi 80    Lo 95    Hi 95
182       6.435371 6.171671 6.699071 6.032077 6.838666
183       6.353675 5.929582 6.777769 5.705081 7.002270
184       6.288319 5.692546 6.884092 5.377163 7.199475

$wt$df_comparison
         time forecasted observed
1  0171-12-18   7.183704     7.25
2  0172-12-18   7.098355     7.25
3  0173-12-18   7.030424     6.75
4  0174-12-18   6.976302     6.75
5  0175-12-19   6.933147     6.75
6  0176-12-18   6.898715     6.75
7  0177-12-18   6.871227     6.75
8  0178-12-18   6.849274     6.75
9  0179-12-18   6.831736     6.75
10 0180-12-18   6.817721     6.50
```

I want to extract few information from these output lists so that a concise summary can be presented. The format of the output in tablular form could be as shown below:

```
var no_obs best_model pt_fcast1 pt_fcast2 pt_fcast3 
wt   181    tbats     6.435371   6.353675  6.288319
ht   150    croston   6.924046   6.963400  6.660900
dist 240    nnetar    0.8252435  1.5224686 2.2196936
```

Need some help here as to how to get this table made!!!!

Comment: My advice is to build up the desired result for a single row (variable), and then use `sapply` to run through the full set.

Comment: @Imo  Can u show in terms of code how it can be done.....not too familiar with sapply()....

Comment: Can you please highlight where you are getting the desired results from? What criteria are you using? For example, to obtain best model, where are the names `croston` and `nnetar` from?? whwere do you get your `dist` variable from??,where do you get `pt_fcast1 pt_fcast2 pt_fcast3` from?? So if we get an Idea where they are one can be able to extract them. Thank you

Comment: using select_forecast() in mafs package...One has too look into it..i think the function in exploded form is there in their github site.. . basically the function employs @17 ts models with their default settings....rt nw the issue is not how these model are being used.....my concern is how to dissect the output to get just the rt kind of info to present to top mgmt. in a concise tabular form....

Comment: extract info  as -ts_lapply[1] # extracting output for first var only
ts_lapply[2] # extracting output for second var only

ts_lapply[1]$wt$best_forecast$mean[1] # extracting the first point forecast from the first variable ...  # Very inefficient way
so filling the col of pt_fcasts1 
pt_fcasts1=c(ts_lapply[1]$wt$best_forecast$mean[1],ts_lapply[2]$ht$best_forecast$mean[1],ts_lapply[3]$dist$best_forecast$mean[1],ts_lapply[4]$inc$best_forecast$mean[1],ts_lapply[5]$width$best_forecast$mean[1],ts_lapply[6]$count$best_forecast$mean[1])   These methods are too inefficient ..need some loop here